# Best way to save read status of a forum post?

Tags: performance, laravel

First: Sorry for the title. I wasn't able to find a more descriptive title.

if we assume that I'm creating a forum software in Laravel with the following scheme of models:

- User (id, name, password)
- Category (id, title)
- Forum (id, category_id, title)
- Thread (id, user_id, title)
- Post (id, user_id, thread_id, body)

First: Would that model structure make sense? Can you recommend a better way?

Then: What would be the best way to save the read-status from a user of a post? For example: Unread threads (/posts) are highlighted in a thread list if there is a posts the user hasn't read. If the user opens the thread all posts in this read get marked as read (if not already) and the thread isn't highlighted anymore. Just like in nearly every forum software: If a thread has unread threads, it is highlighted.

But what is the best way to implement such a read-status in Laravel?

I hope you understand what I mean. If there's anything unclear just ask.
Feel free to edit this question if you think that it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest You to implement same structure as phpBB, it looks solid and I can't think of a way to improve it. Also it fits Your current structure, which also looks pretty good.

Take a look at these two tables:
https://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_topics_track
https://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_forums_track